# Using Storyboard and custom View Controller init

Tags: swift, dependency-injection

When pushing view controller programatically, one can easily do some dependency injection through the init method :

```
let dummyVC = DummyVC(dummyManager: DummyManager())
self.pushViewController(dummyVC, animated: true)
```

Using destination controller :

```
class DummyVC: UIViewController {
    private let dummyManager: DummyManager

    init(dummyManager: DummyManager) {
        self.dummyManager = dummyManager
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
}
```

The previous code is fine because it encapsulates the attribute correctly and clearly show dependencies to external APIs.

When working with Storyboards we cannot choose the init method being called (a custom init method is being called).

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let dummyVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DummyVC") as! DummyVC
dummyVC.dummyManager = DummyManager() // ERROR: would require dummyManager to have public scope
```

Is there any way to inject dependencies the same way while keeping attributes private and constants (let) ?

Comment: Not sure about "keeping attributes private as they won't be changed at runtime". What does one thing have to do with the other?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "keeping attributes private and let constants", edited post to clarify it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

View controllers in storyboards are always initialised using

```
init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
```

there's no way around that.

An alternative would be to have…

```
class DummyVC: UIViewController {
    private var dummyManager: DummyManager!

    func configure(dummyManager: DummyManager) {
        self.dummyManager = dummyManager
    }
}
```

and then…

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let dummyVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DummyVC") as! DummyVC
dummyVC.configure(dummyManager: DummyManager())
```

or

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    switch segue.destination {
    case let dummyVC as DummyVC:
        dummyVC.configure(dummyManager: DummyManager())
    default: 
        break
    }
}
```

Whilst not perfect (using `let` rather than `var`) the property being `private` and an implicitly unwrapped optional means it must be set (or the app will crash on use), and that can only happen from within the containing class.

I've adopted this throughout my apps, and find it quite a nice way to ensure all properties are set. Just remember to update the `configure` func when a property is added to a class.

Comment: thanks for good solution! I decided to use configure method in my project and wanted to ask: is it safe to always force unwrap dummyManager? Maybe it can cause some issues, which are not apparent?

Comment: IMO, it it safe to do so as long as you do not clear it manually (self.dummyManager = nil), as the property is private it can only be used in the same class, when the class is active dummyManager is not nil, until its being deinited (e.g. by pushing another controller). The only thing I can thing of is through the usage of callbacks:
Maybe this would crash (I am not 100% sure):
self.navigationController?.popViewController();
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(.now() + 1) {
    print(self.dummyManager!);
}.
But you can weakify self to avoid this.